# UIImage(data: NSData) error: Missing argument for parameter 'inBundle' in call

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Im storing an `NSURL` for a Facebook profile picture that looks like "http://graph.facebook.com/(id)/picture?type=large" where id is the user's id.

I want to display the image from that url in a `UIImage`

I am trying to do this like so:

```
var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: profilePictureURL)

cell.backgroundImage = UIImage(data: data)
```

But XCode throws an error on that second line that says:

"Missing argument for parameter 'inBundle' in call" but obviously that's not a parameter in this call. I even tried adding it once before and once after like UIImage(data: data, inBundle: nil) and reversed but it said "extra argument inBundle"

Help please!

**** EDIT ****

Found the problem:

```
cell.backgroundImage = UIImage(data: data)
```

should be

```
cell.backgroundImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
```

Comment: this is objc, but you need to convert NSData to a UIImage via imageWithData before you can actually display it. additionally, are your tableview cells being loaded from a custom nib

Comment: @LouisTur The `UIImage(data:)` syntax _is_ equivalent to Objective-C's `imageWithData`.

Comment: @Rob I tried unwrapping data as well like you suggested, but same error. I'll try your 'aside' function and let you know if it works

Comment: @Rob I'll look around

Comment: Found it! cell.backgroundImage should be cell.backgroundImage.image, otherwise it was looking for a UIImageView, not a UIImage

Comment: By the way, in the future, I'd suggest that rather than editing your question with the solution that you go ahead and [post an answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, you want to set the `image` property of `cell.backgroundImage`. Also, you will want to unwrap that optional.

You can do a forced unwrapping:

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: profilePictureURL)
cell.backgroundImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

Or, a little safer, and optional binding:

```
if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: profilePictureURL) {
    cell.backgroundImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```

And, if you want to be especially prudent, and do this asynchronously, it would look like:

```
cell.backgroundImage.image = nil  // initialize it to nil before we go to get image asynchronously

NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(profilePictureURL) { data, response, error in
    if data == nil {
        println("dataTaskWithURL error: \(error)")
    } else {
        if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                cell.backgroundImage.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```